# Multi processes in java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a simulation for a system of several computers, using java. Where each computer is represented by a process (not a thread). I read about using multi processes in java but unfortunately I didn't understand it well and still confused about it.

Which is better to represent such system, a fork/ join model or creating multi processes using the process builder in java ??  What the difference between them??

Comment: It depends what your simulation is simulating exactly. Why have you decided against threads, and why are you considering fork/join, given that it uses threads?

Comment: It is an assignment, and the instructor asked us to use processes and not threads.

Comment: Actually I am still a biggner, and all these concepts are new to me. Excuse me if I am not using the correct or accurate terms

Comment: If that's what the instructor asked, then that's what you'll need to do - use processes, not threads, not fork/join. `ProcessBuilder` is your only tool for this (ignore `Runtime.exec()` - it's a limited version of the same). You'll need to look for tutorials on its usage.

Comment: Is this farming out a subset of the a problem and the process returns a subset of the result which you merge. Probably sorting right?

Answer (score 1):

Fork/join typically refers to the built-in thread pool that the jvm will use for various "parallel" activities. Therefore this concept has nothing to do with "real" processes, as said: it is about threading.

The ProcessBuilder on the other hand enables you to start independent processes that run "outside" of the jvm. This means starting them is significantly more expensive compared to threads. Communication between different processes also requires higher efforts. On the other hand, you can kill another process, something that isn't that simple with threads.

The key difference is that you can multiple threads within a single process, but not vice versa. You can see the process as outer container. Threads are "smaller" boxes that live inside that container.

My advice to a newbie: go with threads. Using threads in Java is way more "natural". And you will also find much more helpful resources on the threading topic compared to processes.

Comment: I think this is to teach the OP about processes, and my guess is that next week they will be actually running those as remote processes on different machines, and no longer simulating several computers.